# Is there any Javascript library that provides drag'n'drop creation/editing of form elements?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, forms, javascript-framework

I am writing a web application that lets a user create their own forms by dragging and dropping input elements (textfields, textareas, etc.).

Currently, the user is able to add / reorder (up or down) / remove form elements, but I need to make them freely draggable.

Some time ago I have seen a tool written in Javascript that lets a user drag&drop tables and then generates SQL from that, but I can't remember where I saw it.

Maybe there is some kind of JS library for this, preferably something for Mootools/jQuery? I searched for it, but didn't get any results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See jQueryUI. Specifically [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).